# No logs on DataDog dashboard (agent installed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, datadog

I'm using DataDog on Mac with the Agent installed. I have verified that the Agent is running fine and that my ENV vars are correct. I wrote the following script to send logs to local files and to the DataDog server:

```js
const { format, transports, createLogger } = require("winston");
const DatadogWinston = require("datadog-winston");

logDir = 'logs'

const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
    transports: [
        new transports.File({ filename: `${logDir}/error.log`, level: 'error' }),
        new transports.File({ filename: `${logDir}/warn.log`, level: 'warn' }),
        new transports.File({ filename: `${logDir}/info.log`, level: 'info' }),
    ],
});

if (process.env.LIVE_LOGGING == "yes") {
    logger.add(new DatadogWinston({
        apiKey: process.env.DATADOG_API_KEY,
        hostname: process.env.DATADOG_HOSTNAME,
        service: 'orch-backend',
        ddsource: 'nodejs'
    }));
}

logger.info('Yo!', new Error("something went wrong!"));
```

Now, I can see logs in my local file but the DataDog dashboard is empty. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting any response from datadog in your local logs? It looks like all of your transports are for files - do you need to possibly use the http transport method shown here? https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/nodejs/?tabs=winston30

Comment: @Ross From what I gather, we don't need the HTTP transport if we have the agent installed and have a `DatadogWinston` logger added. I must say that overall I'm pretty disappointed with DataDog. There's not a single sensible and complete tutorial. :( On the dashboard I see things like Event, Event Id, etc., which I'd love to include in my logs but the examples don't say if and how these can be included. I'm very close to considering another logging service.

Comment: The problem is most likely in your agent config; did you enable log collection and add the winston files as log sources? Can you post your `datadog.yaml`? https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/?tabs=tailfiles#custom-log-collection

Comment: @bwest Well, I finally managed to get it working using the HTTP transform, so all good for now. Maybe someday I'll feel like digging into the issue, but it's better this way since it allows transprency.

Comment: @ankush981 can you share the code, i am kind of stuck at the same issue

Comment: @naresh_321 Here you go: https://pastebin.com/GEztyGLn. I added a file-based logger as well, but you can ignore that part of the code.